# Explicit Column Order in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model with an associated abstract base class like so:

```
class UndeletableModel(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def delete(self, *args, **kargs):
        self.is_deleted = True
        self.save()

class Foo(UndeletableModel):
    bar = CharField(max_length=255)
```

Unfortunately, the previous engineer on the project didn't have to foresight to abstract out this deleting pattern, so the `is_deleted` field was declared explicitly on the `Foo` class after `bar`.  Thus, the code and the database disagree on column order.  Is there any way that I can bring them back into agreement without abandoning my abstraction?

Comment: Is there any specific reason Why the database column ordering important?

Comment: @karthikr that's a bit complicated but can be summed up as "our dba wants it that way".

Comment: You could *try* to fix it with a manual South migration, but i wouldn't know where to begin. Does your dba is using the Django Admin Interface? or getting the results from the db directly?

Comment: I should be more specific.  The goal here is to explicitly state the order of columns on the class.  Using an external migration tool (e.g South), while possible, would be very tedious if it needed to be used every time such an abstraction was made.

Comment: Our dba uses the django admin interface for simple changes, but resorts to raw SQL for more complicated queries.  We have recently completed a major migration so there are still some large cleanups taking place.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to run after the model declaration:

```
field = Foo._meta.get_field('is_deleted')
Foo._meta.local_fields.remove(field)
Foo._meta.local_fields.insert(2, field)
if hasattr(Foo._meta, '_field_cache'):
    del Foo._meta._field_cache
    del Foo._meta._field_name_cache
if hasattr(Foo._meta, '_name_map'):
    del Foo._meta._name_map
```

This will insert the `is_deleted` field just after the second field (the first being the `id` field), but this can of course be any position in the list.

The last steps are important, as `fields` and `get_field` etc. are dependant on the cached entries in `_field_cache`, `_field_name_cache` and `_name_map`. These should be invalidated if the `local_fields` list is changed in any way, so they can be regenerated.

Comment: This would mean either abandoning my abstraction or severely over-complicating it since I'd have to do this for every model that inherits from `UndeletableModel`.  It could be done more generally in a singleton metaclass of `UndeletableModel` (after `__new__`), but that's pretty ugly.

Comment: @astex You can abstract this to a function that takes a class, field name and index, so that it only takes a single line after each model declaration, but yeah, what you're trying to do is pretty explicit for each model, so you will lose some abstraction.

Comment: The goal is to have no additional calls after each individual class definition, abstracting everything out to the abstract model.  As I said, this could be done by moving the hack above to a metaclass's `__new__()` method.  That seems unnecessarily complicated, though.